# How to write a common ClickEvent for many labels?

Tags: c#, winforms, click

I have 10 labels on a panel - and 10 identical ClickEvents (change BackColor).
How could I reduce the code, i.e. write a common procedure ?
Something like:

```
foreach (Control c in panelA.Controls)
if (c.Tag == "abc" && c.is clicked)
c.BackColor = Color.Crimson;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over labels and wire a handler to Click event:

```
foreach (Control c in panelA.Controls)
{
    c.Click += HandleClick;
}
```

Then, in the click handler, you can change the background color by using the `sender` parameter that will contain the label the click was made on:

```
private void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Control)sender).BackColor = Color.Crimson;
}
```

Comment: What about if many answers are - right Answers. Is it somehow relevant which one I assign as Answer or only voting matters?

Comment: @Buena It is solely your choice which answer (if any) gets accepted. You can accept the one that has most votes, but you can also decide to accept the one with zero votes.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you wire each button to the same event handler?

```
button1.Click += ChangeBackColor;
button2.Click += ChangeBackColor;
...
button10.Click += ChangeBackColor;

private void ChangeBackColor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control control = (Control)sender;
    control.BackColor = Color.Crimson;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can assign each label's click event to the same event handler, and then look at the *sender* object in your event handler. It will tell you which label was clicked.

```
private void OnLabelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var label = sender as Label;
    if(label != null)
        label.BackColor = Color.Crimson;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using the sender:

Try something like this:

```
private void label_Click(object sender, EventArg e){
  ((Label)sender) = ..your code
}
```